# Duel Boot Ubuntu / Win 7 on Tablet, How?

Tags: dual-boot

none of the other QA help because I'm not technical.  I just want to try U and then get away from MS entirely.  Creating a boot USB thru Pendrivelinux was impossible - kept directing me to useless sites! If you can help please email me.  Thanks.

Comment: Download Pendrivelinux from this [page](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).  Or download direct from [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if your system is very old (say 10 years) or 5 years. If 5 years , then follow the steps below.

I had a dualboot of ubuntu 12.04 with win vista . If you have a recovery partition in your windows laptop or destop, then choose to shrin your disk after defragmentation and set aside space for your ubuntu. dont format it now and have that partition as RAW .

then , try to install ubuntu by inserting your disk and restarting system . When partitioning , dont disturb your C: drive because, in future , if there is a problem with windows and want to use recovery partition it will erase boot info.

So , install in the space whatever windows was willing to share , inside that allocated space, have three to four imp. partitions - boot (1 gb), swap (2 gb) , home (3 gb) , (usr - 5 gb) etc. according to how want to have partitions and install the system.

Am facing tiny problem with this sort of installation wherein , from the boot menu, if i choose ubuntu to login directly , am seeing a blac screen . so , all the time , am going to recovery mode and then boot normally from there . You may also get this problem licely but there are worcarounds , I believe , mostly if your graphics card is slow or old i suppose .... Asc second opinion from more experts if you want to as I myself need help here.